# How good can Least Squares be?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

We are given a matrix $A$  of full columns rank and a vector $b$ of appropriate sizes and want so solve the problem $\min_x || Ax-b||_2$. I know that the best solution is given by $x^\star=A^+b$ where $A^+$ denotes the More-Penrose-Inverse.

My question is now the following: Can we say anything about how large the norm will still be, something like $||Ax^*-b||_2 \leq d$ or $||Ax^*-b||\geq d$ for some constant d?

I tried plugging in the solution, but was unable to simplify the term. Does anyone know any common results?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If matrix $A$ is fixed and has no full column rank (i.e. its columns are linearly dependent), then by choosing $b$ the expression $||Ax^*-b||$ can be made as large or as small as you want.

Comment: I forgot to include, that the Moore-Penrose-Inverse yields the best approximation only if $A$ has full column rank. But if this condition is additionally given, can $||Ax^\star-b||$ still be made as large as you want?

Comment: $0 \leq \min_{x}\Vert Ax-b\Vert\leq\Vert A0-b\Vert=\Vert b\Vert$ is a pretty useless bound, but a bound nonetheless. Moreover, this bound is tight in the sense that both sides can be achieved (see the comment of kabenyuk and answer of TSF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such bound is possible. Consider $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $b=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\ b'\end{matrix}\right)$ where $b'\in\mathbb{R}$. The solution to the optimization problem is given by $x^\star= \left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\end{matrix}\right)$ yet $\|Ax^\star-b\|_2 = |b'|$ which is arbitrary in $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Actually the same argument holds with the even simpler example using $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)$, $b=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ b'\end{matrix}\right)$, and $x^\star=0$.